# Parsing a JSON column of an R data frame

Tags: mysql, json, r

My data comes in from mySQL as a data frame that looks like:

```
  id users_id value                                                                                                             

2    29937  {"event":"VirtualPageview","eventName":"VirtualPageview","virtualUrl":"/login/mood","fromUrl":"/login"}
3    29937  {"event":"VirtualPageview","eventName":"VirtualPageview","virtualUrl":"/login/done","fromUrl":"/login/mood"}
8    77347  {"event":"VirtualPageview","eventName":"VirtualPageview","virtualUrl":"/signup/survey","fromUrl":"/signup/account"}
```

I am trying to get it to look like:

```
  id users_id   event             eventName         virtualUrl    fromUrl                                                                                                    
  2    29937   "VirtualPageview"  "VirtualPageview" "/login/mood" "/login"
```

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997283/extract-format-and-separate-json-already-stored-in-a-data-frame-column) is close, but the original data format is different. I would rather not import 4 libraries if I get away with less.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
library(jsonlite)
```

Then turning the whole column into a string and pasting on `[]`

```
fromJSON(paste0('[',toString(head(df$value)),']'))
```

> ```
>         event       eventName     virtualUrl         fromUrl
> 1 VirtualPageview VirtualPageview    /login/mood          /login
> 2 VirtualPageview VirtualPageview    /login/done     /login/mood
> 3 VirtualPageview VirtualPageview /signup/survey /signup/account
> ```

```
df <-cbind(df[,c("id","users_id")],fromJSON(paste0('[',toString(head(df$value)),']')))
```

> ```
> id users_id           event       eventName     virtualUrl         fromUrl
>     2    29937 VirtualPageview VirtualPageview    /login/mood          /login
>     3    29937 VirtualPageview VirtualPageview    /login/done     /login/mood
>     8    77347 VirtualPageview VirtualPageview /signup/survey /signup/account
> ```